# Spring's ResponseBodyAdvice: Order of execution?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, httpresponse, spring-4

I want to implement a custom `ResponseBodyAdvice`, which simply looks for `Page<?>` and then adds the number of total elements to the response headers.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class PageResponseAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return Page.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        ((Page<?>) body).getTotalElements();
        ...
    }

}
```

The questions are:

- Why is `body` (within the `beforeBodyWrite` method) of type `MappingJacksonValue`?
- Is there a better way to achieve this? / Am I using the wrong interceptor?

I don't want to take care of wrapper classes, though I just want the plain unmodified `Page` object within the `beforeBodyWrite` method.

---

### EDIT:

I now just `extend AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice`. This works well, but doesn't *feel* right. Maybe someone still got a better idea.

Here's the code for `Page -> Content-Range Header`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class PageResponseAdvice extends AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice {
    @Override public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return super.supports(returnType, converterType) && Page.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override protected void beforeBodyWriteInternal(MappingJacksonValue bodyContainer, MediaType contentType, MethodParameter returnType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        Page<?> page = ((Page<?>) bodyContainer.getValue());
        Long from = null;
        Long to = null;
        if(page.getTotalElements() > 0 && page.getNumberOfElements() > 0) {
            from = Integer.valueOf(page.getNumber()).longValue()*page.getSize();
            to = from + page.getNumberOfElements() - 1;
        }
        response.getHeaders().add(
                HttpHeaders.CONTENT_RANGE,
                ContentRangeEncoder.encode(
                        "items",
                        from,
                        to,
                        page.getTotalElements()
                )
        );
        response.getHeaders().add(
                HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_RANGES,
                "items"
        );
    }
}
```

(And if anyone is interested. Here's the `ContentRangeEncoder`):

```
public class ContentRangeEncoder {
    private static final Pattern TYPE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
    private static final Predicate<String> TYPE_PATTERN_PREDICATE = TYPE_PATTERN.asPredicate();

    public static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> String encode(String unit, T from, T to, T length) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if(unit != null) {
            Assert.isTrue(TYPE_PATTERN_PREDICATE.test(unit));
            sb.append(unit).append(" ");
        }

        if(from == null && to == null) {
            sb.append("*");
        } else {
            Assert.notNull(from);
            Assert.notNull(to);
            Assert.isTrue(from.compareTo(to) <= 0);
            sb.append(from).append("-").append(to);
        }
        sb.append("/");
        if(length == null) {
            sb.append("*");
        } else {
            Assert.isTrue(to == null || length.compareTo(to) > 0);
            sb.append(length);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As to why the body is of type `MappingJacksonValue`, it depends on your configuration and your particular handler method's return value.

As a side note, `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`adds `JsonViewResponseBodyAdvice` to the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`, and if this `ResponseBodyAdvice` bean is invoked before yours, that would explain why the body is a `MappingJacksonValue`. The body is passed around from one `ResponseBodyAdvice` bean to the next, each returning the body in whatever "form" it sees fit.

Here's an extract of 'AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice', superclass of `JsonViewResponseBodyAdvice` to see what happens to the body:

```
public final Object beforeBodyWrite(@Nullable Object body,
    MethodParameter returnType, ..., ..., ..., ...) {

    //...

    MappingJacksonValue container = getOrCreateContainer(body);

    //...

    return container;
}
```